# Python - difference in confusion matrix dimension

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, confusion-matrix

I have a question about confusion matrix. I use cross validation to split 148 instances for two array - test and train. Than I call something like that:

```
def GenerateResult:
   clf = OneVsRestClassifier(GaussianNB())
   clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
   predictions = clf.predict(x_test)
   accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
   confusion_mtrx = confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions)
```

that is a loop for KFold -> I call function from up:

```
for train_idx, test_idx in pf.split(x_array):
       x_train, x_test = x_array[train_idx], x_array[test_idx]
       y_train, y_test = y_array[train_idx], y_array[test_idx]
       acc, confusion= GenerateResult(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)
       results['First'].append(acc)
       confusion_dict['First'].append(confusion)
```

Then I sum result and calculate mean

```
np_gausian = np.asarray(results['gaussian'])
print("[First] Mean: {}".format(np.mean(np_gausian)))

print(confusion_dict['gaussian'])
```

And I have a problem. In my 148 instances I have 4 classes in output and when I use that loop for KFold I have result with two different confusion matrix.
First confusion matrix 3x3:

```
[[36  1  1]

 [15 17  1]

 [ 0  0  3]]
```

Second 4x4 :

```
[[ 0  2  0  0]

 [ 0 41  2  0]

 [ 0 12 16  0]

 [ 0  0  1  0]]
```

I think that I have a problem with it becouse in my 148 instance I have

- Class 1 - 2 ea
- Class 2 - 81 ea
- Class 3 - 61 ea
- Class 4 - 4 ea
- All Class - 148

What should I do with it? How can I sum that confusion matrix? What if I change the number of split in KFold? I try to use Pandas but I don't have an idea how to do it. Please help, I use sk-learn for it

Comment: I think your problem stems from the fact that class 1 has only two observations and when you split your test they both fall in the second fold. Try StratifiedKFold instead of KFold and if this doesn't help manually move one of the observations from class 1 to the other fold.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comment by @KRKirov, the reason for this is due to Kfold cross-validation splitting of data into folds, some classes are not present in the test set of that fold.

For example, if class1 is not present in `y_test`, and not predicted also in `predictions`, then the `confusion_matrix` code will infer automatically that there are only three classes present in the data and generate the matrix according to that.

You can force the confusion_matrix to use all classes by setting the [`labels` param](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html):-

> labels : array, shape = [n_classes], optional
>
> ```
> List of labels to index the matrix. This may be used to reorder or
> select a subset of labels. If none is given, those that appear at
> least once in y_true or y_pred are used in sorted order.
> ```

by doing this:

```
confusion_mtrx = confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions, 
                                 labels = np.unique(y_array))
```

You need to pass the y_array or unique labels from y_array to the GenerateResult() method.

Comment: Ok, It's works. Also answer from @KRKirov works. But I have another question - how should I sum that confusion matrix that I get?

Comment: Ok, I found it. We should sum all confusion matrix to the one by that code. Thanks for all

Comment: @Zarobiek If it helped, consider upvoting/accepting the answer.